# How to use router-view for tabs in Vuejs?

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I have using vuesax [ https://github.com/lusaxweb/vuesax ] for tabs. In vs-tabs i have multiple router-view. I want call show different vue template file for respected tabs of router-view.

Here is app.vue code.

```
   <template>
   <div id="app">
  <div class="">
   <h3 style="color: #0DB26B;">
    home <mark class="red">New</mark> Design
  </h3>
<vs-tabs  :color="colorx" alignment="fixed" >
  <vs-tab label="Home" >
    <router-link
            tag="button" class="btn btn-link" to="/home">Home
          </router-link>
    <div class="con-tab-ejemplo">
      <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
  </vs-tab>
  <vs-tab label="Add Invoice" >
  <router-link
            tag="button" class="btn btn-link" to="/card">Card
          </router-link>
    <div class="con-tab-ejemplo">
      <router-view></router-view>

    </div>
  </vs-tab>
  <vs-tab label="Profile">
    <div class="con-tab-ejemplo">
      <router-view></router-view>

       </div>
      </vs-tab>
      </vs-tabs>
    </div>

  </div>
 </template>
```

Here is my router code [index.js]:

```
   import Vue from 'vue'
   import Router from 'vue-router';
   import Home from '@/components/Home';

   import Card from '@/components/Card';


   Vue.use(Router);

   let router = new Router({


   routes: [
    {
        path: '/home',
        name:"Home",
        component: Home,

    },
    {
        path: '/card',
        name:"Card",
        component: Card,

         },

      ]


   });
  export default router;
```

My issue:

1.) same vue template is shown in all vs-tabs router-view?
2.) How to set router-link for vs-tabs?

Here is my screen shots:

Any help much appreciated pls..

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$router.push` method

```
   <div>
      <vs-tabs color="success" alignment="fixed">
        <vs-tab label="Home" @click="$router.push('/home')">
          <div class="con-tab-ejemplo">
            <router-view></router-view>
          </div>
        </vs-tab>
        <vs-tab label="Add Invoice" @click="$router.push('/card')">
          <div class="con-tab-ejemplo">
            <router-view></router-view>
          </div>
        </vs-tab>
        <vs-tab label="Profile"></vs-tab>
      </vs-tabs>
    </div>
```

Demo on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vuesax-base-9xiog)

Comment: Thanks for answering. How to set router-link for vs-tab?

Comment: I think you can use `router-link` normally. Does it work?

Comment: Separate new menu creating you can check my screen shot. Two home button is created. When i click on Home tabs it should it list data tables and click on add invoice it should show card view in router-view

Comment: is it possible to use router-link into vs-tab like <vs-tab label="Home" to="/home" >

Comment: i want remove router-link button Home/card which is created below tabs

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI, you cannot use `to` or `:to`.  At least not with vuesax v3.  `vs-tab` does not appear to recognize that prop.  It only works with `@click`.

**If you want to do this with child components** you can use nested routes.  Here is what the nested routes would look like.  From the example above, instead of using the root `App.vue` assume we have routed to a child component called `Main.vue` at url `/main`.  Your `router.js` file would look like this

```
{
    path: '/main',
    component: Main,
    children: [
        {
        path: '',
        redirect: 'home'
        },
        {
        path: 'home',
        component Home
        },
        {
        path: 'card',
        component: Card
        }
    ]
}
```

So browsing to `/main` redirects to `/main/home` url using `Home` tab and switching to the `Add Invoice` tab becomes url `/main/card`.

The links in the template need to reflect the above paths.  So remove the `/` to become `@click="$router.push('home')` and `@click="$router.push('card')`.